# calling Post Login activity from webview

Tags: java, android, webview

My first screen is an activity to fill up a server information, once the user saves that information , a webview will be launched with external webpage related to that server for authentication purpose. User provides login details and if the authentication is successful, I want to show a different screen which I want to handle in postlogin . Is there a way to detect that user has finished authentication in webview? This is what I am trying in my code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    this.setContentView(R.layout.launchwv);
    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("loginURL");
    urlWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.browserWebview);

    urlWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error){
            handler.proceed();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            if(url.contains(getResources().getString(R.string.loginTitle)))
            {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                String result = "SampleString";
                mIntent.putExtra("return_value", result);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
                finish();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }); 
    urlWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
    urlWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    urlWebView.loadUrl(url);
}

public void onFinish(View v){
  //Read result string from mIntent and do Post login activity

}
```

Comment: Have you control over the server?! Than you can, after a succesfull login, redirect to "http://domain.com/loginSuccess" and override in WebViewClient ´onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)´ and catch the url...

Comment: Right now after successful login it goes to <b>domain.com/LOGINCOMPELETE </b>, I don't have control over the screen which asks for authentication because authentication is delegated to a third party.